# Identify gcd(26,553) with extended euclid algorithm

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

Identify, using the extended euclid algorithm:

$gcd(553,26)$

also the numbers:

$u,v \in \mathbb{Z}~~~~~~~~553u+26v=gcd(553,26)$

My calculation gives me $1$, so there isn't a real gcd, can someone approve this?

What's with $u$ and $v$ now?
I can't solve this equation with any numbers $\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "real gcd"? If your calculation gives $1$, then it means that the gcd is $1$.

Comment: Probably that's just a term I made up. Because even of prime numbers a common divisor is 1, always. So I thought 1 is not a "real gcd". Just ignore that.

Comment: for the latter u need to use the extended euclidian algorithm see here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

It is kind of using the euclidian algorithm 'backwards'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$553=26\times21+7$$
$$26=3\times7+5$$
$$7=1\times5+2$$
$$5=2\times2+1$$
$$2=2\times1$$
Hence $(553,26)=1$

Now
$$1=5-2\times2\\=5-2\times(7-5)\\=3\times5-2\times7\\=3(26-3.7)-2.7\\=3.26-11.7\\=3.26-11(553-26.21)\\=234\times26-11\times553$$

So $u=-11$ and $v=234$